# Reboot Crontab on AWS EC2 not executing

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, cron, reboot

I am having difficulties getting my docker-compose command to run on reboot in my EC2 instance. I have been through many responses with a similar question but have been unsuccessful so far.

In my EC2 instance, I have the following crontab set up (via `crontab -e`) which fails to execute when the instance is rebooted:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && sudo systemctl enable docker && cd /home/<user>/<repo_name> && docker-compose up --build -d
```

Running the command manually successfully runs the docker-compose file, and I have checked that other crontabs execute successfully, a quick `* * * * * echo "test" > text.txt` runs as intended.

My question is, is there a way to get this crontab to execute successfully on reboot, or is there another way that is perhaps better to get my containers up and running?

Comment: May be you should use Event Bridge and Lambda to execute the script on EC2 reboot

Comment: Definitely a solution, might it not be overkill for running a simple bash command?

Comment: Try this one https://youtu.be/JDbhl4h8-jY

Comment: Are you sure it's not running at all? Could it be failing with an error? Are you adding this to the ec2-user crontab or the root crontab?

Comment: Have you checked the cron logs?  Try to add `> /var/log/cronfailinglogs 2>&1` to the expression too. Maybe one of the command fails . Also , you do not need `systemctl enable docker` . It's a one time operation.

Comment: @MarkB I've tried adding it to both ec2-user crontab and the root crontab but neither seem to work.

Comment: @Riz I will try this, and thanks for the advice re ```systemctl enable```